# iOS UINavigationController not shown on ChildView

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad, uinavigationcontroller

in my project i have loginviewcontroller in this view i hide navigationcontroller in viewWillAppear method 
if login successful i have below code

```
-(void)gotoCheckinPage{
DashboardViewController *v = [[DashboardViewController alloc]
                            initWithNibName:@"DashboardViewController" bundle:nil];

UINavigationController *navCon = [[UINavigationController alloc]
                                  initWithRootViewController:v];

[navCon.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navbar_bg.png"]
                           forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

[self presentViewController:navCon animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

but in dashboard view controller navigationcontroller not shown

this is how i hide navigationcontroller in loginview

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:animated];
[super viewWillAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:animated];
[super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}
```

if i comment the line :

```
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:animated];
```

there is no problem but want to get hidden navigationcontroller in loginview then set to active in other view controllers

any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write down this code in your view . in which you wants to show navigation

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = NO;
   }
```

Comment: ok this works fine. but i don't get it. i set navigationBarHidden NO in viewWillDisappear why should i do the same thing again on other views?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add this in your LoginViewController:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES; // Where you want to hide it.
}
```

And in the DashboardViewController:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = NO; // Where you want to show it.
}
```